# Casperjs how do i add variable to fill form function and the send the varible externally via terminal

Tags: variables, phantomjs, casperjs

With casperjs, how can i add variable to fill form function and the send the variable externally via terminal.

I list the code i have for form fill below. I want to be able to add variables to it then pass these via command line. Any help would be appreciated.

```
casper.thenOpen(url2, function(){
    this.fill('form[name="LoginForm"]', {
        'username': 'var1here',
        'password': 'var2here' },
        true);
});
```

Once i have the variable setup, how do i pass these via command line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You want to pass arguments via the command line to your Casper script, right? [Go read the doc](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use named parameters :

```
var userinput = casper.cli.get("userinput");
var passinput = casper.cli.get("passinput");
```

And call your script like this :

```
casperjs test.js --userinput=test --passinput=test
```

In your script you will be able to test if the params is set like this

```
if (casper.cli.has("userinput")) {
}

if (casper.cli.has("passinput")) {
}
```

More information about casper.cli there => http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this and got it working by adding the following snippets of code into the right place in my casperjs script :

```
var userinput = casper.cli.get(0)
var passinput = casper.cli.get(1)
```

Then i just set my fill form section like this :

```
casper.thenOpen(url, function(){
this.fill('form[name="LoginForm"]', {
    'username': userinput ,   <-- this being (0) if you use this function remove this-->
    'password': passinput ,  <-- this being (1) if you use this function remove this-->
true);
});
```

Comment: @BriceFavre can you help me with this >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563640/php-execution-phantom-js-works-but-casperjs-does-not-work-permission-denied