# php execution phantom js works but casperjs does not work permission denied

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs, casperjs

okay so i am running centos 6.5 with zpanel setup.
this then has phantom js and casperjs both setup and working it the

```
/usr/local/bin
```

directory.

i use this php command for phantomjs and casperjs

```
 echo exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs --version 2>&1');
```

phantomjs works fine but casperjs gives me this error

```
sh: /usr/local/bin/casperjs: Permission denied
```

can anyone out there help me fix this problem it is just a pain

```
output for ls -al casperjs


   [root@cyber-hosted ~]# ls -al casperjs
total 100
 drwxr-xr-x  10 apache root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 .
dr-xr-x---.  5 root   root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root 1220 Feb  4 15:49 casperjs.gemspec
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   75 Feb  4 15:49 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root 4929 Feb  4 15:49 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root 1524 Feb  4 15:49 CONTRIBUTORS.md
drwxr-xr-x   6 root   root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 docs
drwxr-xr-x   8 root   root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   12 Feb  4 15:49 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   71 Feb  4 15:49 .gitignore
 -rw-r--r--   1 root   root    0 Feb  4 15:49 .gitmodules
 -rw-r--r--   1 root   root  145 Feb  4 15:49 .jshintignore
 -rw-r--r--   1 root   root  528 Feb  4 15:49 .jshintrc
 -rw-r--r--   1 root   root 1066 Feb  4 15:49 LICENSE.md
 -rw-r--r--   1 root   root  552 Feb  4 15:49 Makefile
 drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 modules
 -rw-r--r--   1 root   root  767 Feb  4 15:49 package.json
 -rw-r--r--   1 root   root 4558 Feb  4 15:49 README.md
 drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 rpm
 drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 samples
 drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 src
 drwxr-xr-x   7 root   root 4096 Feb  4 15:49 tests
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root 3093 Feb  4 15:49 .travis.yml
```

output for ls -al /usr/local/bin (where i execute in php)

```
total 37744
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 Feb  4 22:08 .
drwxr-xr-x. 11 root root     4096 Feb  2 00:49 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       27 Feb  4 22:08 casperjs -> /root/casperjs/bin/ca                         sperjs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 38641084 Feb  4 15:48 phantomjs
```

Comment: theres got to be somebody out there to help i have tried changing permissions i cannot use sudo due to no tty

Comment: what are the permission of file, try to chmod a+x casperjs

Comment: i have tried this but it still fails unfortunatly i dont know the permission i forgot the command i will have a look when i am home from college

Comment: i have added the output in my above thread @BriceFavre

Comment: @BriceFavre the out puts are above bro any help would be appreciated i can see theres problems and when i try to chmod casper js i cannot change it for some reason it just does not change

Comment: You might try changing the permission of the target - /root/casperjs/bin/casperjs. Sym links are not affected by `chmod`. Ref: http://superuser.com/questions/303040/how-do-file-permissions-apply-to-symlinks

Comment: i tried this but i now have the answer and have just finished writing it check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one of my own questions answered by myself I am happy that I am starting to understand this new Hobby :) 
well any way luckily I am using virtual box whilst developing my server to my needs and every time I complete a task 
like install Zpanel configure it I create a clone.

so what I done is I reverted back to my server set up before the PhantomJS and CasperJS.
I then installed both PhantomJS and CasperJS using the following methods and then used my test.php script to test
server functionality

Okay I used the following to install PhantomJS

```
# wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-i686.tar.bz2
# tar xvf phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2
# cp phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
```

Then I use these Commands For CasperJS install

```
# cd /opt
# wget https://codeload.github.com/n1k0/casperjs/legacy.zip/1.1-beta3
# unzip 1.1-beta3
# ln -s n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9/ casperjs
# ln -s /opt/casperjs/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/
```

I then created this on my server

PHP Test File Test.php

```
<?php
    ## This Function Below Sets PhantomJs So CasperJS Can Use It
    putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
    echo "Running PhantomJS version: ";
    echo exec('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs --version 2>&1');
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Running CasperJS version: ";
    echo exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs --version 2>&1');

?>
```

After this I ran Test.php And got this result

```
Running PhantomJS version: 1.9.7
Running CasperJS version: 1.1.0-beta3
```

My Server Now Runs CasperJs With PhantomJS

Please Uprate This Answer if you like it :)

Comment: thanks！！`putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");` is  necessary。

Comment: the reason of `Permission denied` is you install the casperjs in the `/root`