# Execute the casperjs on the command line is Ok, but there is an error, when it called by a php script

Tags: casperjs

First of all, I have installed `phantomjs`.
the code of `test.js` is:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
if(casper.cli.has(0)){
    var id = casper.cli.get(0);
    casper.start("http://test.com/index.php?a=screenshot&id="+id, function() {
        this.captureSelector(id+'.png', '.content');
    });
    casper.run();
}else{
    casper.exit();
}
```

and when I run this
 `/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js 124`
on the command line is Ok, and there is an image(124.png) generated in the directory.
But when I use the php to excute the command ,there is an error.
My PHP code:

```
    $id = 124;
    $handle = popen('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs --version 2>&1','r');
    $read = stream_get_contents($handle);
    echo $read;//1.9.7
    pclose($handle);
    $handle = popen('/usr/local/bin/casperjs screenshot.js '.$id.' 2>&1','r');
    $read = stream_get_contents($handle);
    echo $read;//Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?
    pclose($handle);
```

when I access the php script througth the browser，the page output `1.9.7 Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?`

Answer (score 0):

get the answer from [php execution phantom js works but casperjs does not work permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563640)
before excute the command , an environment variable should be added.
`putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs")`

```
putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
$handle = popen('/usr/local/bin/casperjs --version 2>&1','r');
$read = stream_get_contents($handle);
echo $read;
pclose($handle);
```

that's ok!